# Returning Sources with statefulMapConcat

Tags: scala, akka-stream

In an akka-http websocket app, I have a Route that echoes back the given messages, and I also need to maintain state in the app. So the following works fine:

```
  override protected def routes: Route =
    pathSuffix("echo") {
      handleWebSocketMessages(echoMessageFlow)
    }

  def echoMessageFlow: Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = Flow[Message].statefulMapConcat { () =>
    implicit var state = new SessionState()
    msg: Message =>
    List(msg, msg, msg) // echo the message back 3 times
  }
```

However, I also need to throttle the echo messages so only one happens per second. So I'd like to be able to do this:

```
  def echoMessageFlow: Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = Flow[Message].statefulMapConcat { () =>
    implicit var state = new SessionState()
    msg: Message =>
    Source(List(msg, msg, msg)).throttle(1, 1 second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping) 
  }
```

However, the function returned by `statefulMapConcat` requires that it be an `Iterable`. Is there any way to return a `Source` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`flatMapConcat`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#flatmapconcat) (or `flatMapMerge`, if you need parallelization) and give it a function that produces a `Source` for each incoming element.

Each produced `Source` can be throttled by appending the `throttle` combinator, the same way you did above.

Lastly, if you want your `Source` to be stateful, you can create it by using [`Source.unfold`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#unfold).

Example below (using count of produced messages as internal state):

```
  def echoMessageFlow: Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = Flow[Message].flatMapConcat { msg: Message => 
    Source.unfold(0){ count: Int ⇒ 
      if (count < 3)
        Some(count + 1, msg)
      else
        None
    }.throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: how to preserve `SessionState` mentioned in the question?